# c# Make use of ApplicationDbContext in my Classe's static Method to reuse in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm diving into ASP.Net MVC Core 2.0 and having a little trouble with the DbContext as a lot people seem to have because the documentation by MS is frustrating as I think.

I've got a running MVC-App with a DevicesController that serves a ViewModel into my Index.cshtml View. Iterating over the Model-Data works fine and a list is generated.

Now there are some column which contain different manufacturers-ids.

To get The Manufaturer-Objects i my plan was to create a Helper-Class with a static method GetManufacturer(int id) that returns an Object of Type Manufacturer.

And here's the problem: how do I get contact to the DbContext? Because I'm using the identity-Methods I need an instance of ApplicationDbContext.

I've tried a lot from MSDN-Posts or here on SO but none of theese tipps helped me solving my problem.

Look, this is what I've done so far:
Helper Class

```
public class Helper
{
    ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public Helper(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Manufacturer GetManufacturer(int id)
    {
        var manufacturer = _context.Manufacturers.Where(m => m.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
        return manufacturer;
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to make use of this method in my view. I've shortend it a little bit:

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Devices Overview";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

var helper = new Helper();

<span>The Manufacturers Name is: 
@helper.GetManufacturer(1).ManufacturerName</span>}
```

helper-instance is now awaiting an argument of type ApplicationDbContext this is not my intention.

I know in recent threads I've read about the dependency injection and I think here's my problem the ApplicationDbContext is not injected into my class. But how to do so?

It would be very helpful, if you could help me get rid of this or also I'm open for a different solution.

Thanks in advance,
monsee

Comment: You can send a ViewModel to your View, filled with the Data(ManufacturerName) you want. Or call `var helper = ServiceLocator.GetService<Helper>()` in your View, if you have your Helper and ApplicationDbContext registered in your DI Container.

Comment: Using a helper class which is called in the view and access the db can be done and definitely has its place, but would be very inappropriate in your example here.  Build out your view model in your controller, that's the entire purpose of a view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're trying to apply a concept which is violating the MVC principle an the whole idea behind it. In MVC, the Data Access happens through the **Controller**. Also, you see having a class called `Helper` is not helpful at all, get rid of it. What you probably trying to establish is similar to a pattern called the "Repository" pattern.

Have a **ViewModel** for your **View**, have the Manufacturer Data placed in the **ViewModel**, and in View, display what's in the ViewModel only. Don't try to gather Data from somewhere from the View, it will end up in a mess.

MVC will work best if base rules are applied. I think you should follow the [ASP.NET MVC Tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc) to learn the [basic principles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview).

If you're interested in optimising your data access, [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt703433.aspx) about "writing Clean Code in ASP.NET Core with Dependency Injection" is just right - but only once you have a higher understanding of the whole architecture.

Comment: Good Morning everyone, I've expected that my way won't be a valid one. Due to my learning progress and my intention to do it the right way, I will review my code and extend my view model. I agree that this is the best way either MVC or not but no own creations. Many thanks for your detailed reply and your help.